# Clicking on database echo and get info from the same ID

Tags: php, html, css, sql

Second time I come here for help. I have to use PHP for a school project and with limited time it's hard to learn what you need. anyway, I am trying to make a table with product images and name of the same product, this I have done successfully, however. I want to click the name of one of the products and get up info from the same database on that unique ID somewhere else on the page, maybe this isnt possible or my code is just not made out to work doing that, but I seriously have no idea what to do at the moment, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM produkt JOIN bild ON bild.idBild = produkt.idProdukt JOIN ingrediens ON ingrediens.idIngrediens = produkt.idProdukt");
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Idun af Varla goes</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stil.css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
<center>

<div id="container-banner">
<div id="banner">
    <p>
        <img src="banner.png">
    </p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="container-smallstandard">
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>   
<li>
    <a href='#'>
    <span>Nyheter</span>
    </a>
</li>

<li class='active'>
    <a href='#'>
    <span>Produkter</span>
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href='#'>
    <span>Återförsäljare</span>
    </a>
</li>

<li class='last'>
    <a href='#'>
    <span>Kontakta oss</span>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="container-bigstandard">
<p>

</p>
</div>

<div id="container-bottomsmall">
<p>Mail.</p>
</div>
```

This is the php that prints out my images and product names, one I click the name I want the ID of that unique entry to print out the rest of the rows with the same id on another part of the page.

```
<div id="container-bigstandardphp" align="left">
<p>

<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $imgData = base64_encode($row['Bild']);
    ?>
    <table class = "blubb">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $imgData ?>" />     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['Produkt_Namn'] ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
</p>
</div>
</center>

<?php
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "somewhere else on the page"? Do you want to open a new page and show more information or do you want an modal window to open without haveing the page reload?

Comment: yeah, I don't want to reload the page if possible.

Comment: Either use Ajax, or load all the data, and then set it to display none, and then you can show it again on click.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) for this:

```
$("#unique_id").on("click", function(e) {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "your_endpoint",
        data: $(this).attr("id").serialize();
        success: function(data) { 
           //append data
        },
        error: function(data) {
           //append data
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd be getting something like this `Produkt_Id` along with `Produkt_Namn`.
Replace `<td><?php echo $row['Produkt_Namn'] ?></td>` with:

```
<a href="edit.php?id="<?php echo $row['Produkt_Id'] ?> >
 <td><?php echo $row['Produkt_Namn'] ?></td>
</a>
```

Make new page edit.php and put following code:

```
<?php
  $id = $_GET["id"];
  // You'll get the product id in $id.
  // Run the `SELECT` query for what ever fields you want of that id.
  // See example query:

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM produkt WHERE Produkt_Id=".$id; 
  $result = mysqli_query($sql) or die($sql);
  // I suppose 'Produkt_Id' is the field which contains id of 
  // the product in the database.

  //You'll be getting the product info with $result.
  //Hope you can then display the info as per your need may be within a table or anything.
?>
```

This info will be displayed on the new page i.e `edit.php`. If you want to display the info on the previous page then just use iframe on that previous page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're passing the `GET` value directly into the query without cleaning it first :( - http://www.slideshare.net/phpcodemonkey/exploiting-php-with-php#